# How to run spring boot jar from script file on Mac?

Tags: java, spring-boot, macos, shell

I have a Spring Boot application which I'm running from Intellij. I'm passing a lot of environment variables which are being referenced in application.yml.

I'm passing env variables in below section in Intellij:

For e.g.:
LOCAL_FILE_PATH=\Users\ABC\Documents\files

[image]

These are referenced in the application.yml as below:

local:
file:
path: ${LOCAL_FILE_PATH}

Now, I want to run the jar on Mac from a shell script.
I have tried several things like setting up via export in script, passing them via spring_boot_json in script, etc. but it didn't work for me.

Can someone please let me know what I'm missing.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the environment variables in the script itself. You need to use `-D` appender for each variable. Refer the example below:

```
java -jar jarname.jar -Dlocal.file.path=/path/to/file -Done.more.var=ABCD
```

And in you application.yml file, you can reference these like below:

```
local:
  file:
    path: ${local.file.path}
one:
  more:
    var: ${one.more.var}
```

**PS:** The env variables you are passing in IntelliJ, that also works like above internally. Exporting variables in shell script will not make it visible to your java program, you need to pass it in command line arguments always.

Comment: I had tried this for my scenario. I have around 12-15 env variables. It didn't work. I will try with a simple app with 1-2 params and see.